# Find only the time periods on a schedule where the time of employees overlap. (AKA those times where everyone is present)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a list of employees with times they are working and each employee has differing times they are on the job and I need to figure out how to determine ONLY the times where everyone is present at the same time. For instance I need to truncate times where only 1 or a few employees are present but not all.

| **sDate | startTime | endTime | name** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-23 00:00:00.000 | 2023-02-23 08:00:00.000 | 2023-02-23 10:00:00.000 | John |
| 2023-02-23 00:00:00.000 | 2023-02-23 10:30:00.000 | 2023-02-23 12:00:00.000 | John |
| 2023-02-23 00:00:00.000 | 2023-02-23 13:00:00.000 | 2023-02-23 17:00:00.000 | John |
| 2023-02-23 00:00:00.000 | 2023-02-23 08:30:00.000 | 2023-02-23 09:00:00.000 | Anita |
| 2023-02-23 00:00:00.000 | 2023-02-23 09:30:00.000 | 2023-02-23 20:00:00.000 | Anita |

I tried using a lag function to determine the overlapping segments so that I could cut off the times appropriately, but I don't seem to be getting the results I'm looking for.

```
DECLARE @tmpSchedules TABLE (
    sDate DATETIME
    ,startTime DATETIME
    ,endTime DATETIME
    ,name varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO @tmpSchedules
SELECT '20230223', '20230223 08:00', '20230223 10:00', 'John'
UNION ALL
SELECT '20230223', '20230223 10:30', '20230223 12:00', 'John'
UNION ALL
SELECT '20230223', '20230223 13:00', '20230223 17:00', 'John'
UNION ALL
SELECT '20230223', '20230223 08:30', '20230223 09:00', 'Anita'
UNION ALL
SELECT '20230223', '20230223 09:30', '20230223 20:00', 'Anita'

select * from @tmpSchedules

SELECT CA.sDate, CA.startTime, CA.endTime
,CASE
WHEN LAG(CA.endTime) OVER (ORDER BY CA.starttime) > CA.startTime THEN 0
ELSE 1
END OVL
FROM @tmpSchedules CA
```

Expected results would be similar to

| sDate | startTime | endTime | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-23 00:00:00 | 2023-02-23 08:30:00 | 2023-02-23 09:00:00 | 30 |
| 2023-02-23 00:00:00 | 2023-02-23 09:30:00 | 2023-02-23 10:00:00 | 30 |
| 2023-02-23 00:00:00 | 2023-02-23 10:30:00 | 2023-02-23 12:00:00 | 90 |
| 2023-02-23 00:00:00 | 2023-02-23 13:00:00 | 2023-02-23 17:00:00 | 240 |

[image: Visual of Schedule Overlaps]

Comment: [Here's my typical approach](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5854/using-tsql-to-find-events-that-overlap-or-dont-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Comment: It's not clear what the purpose of `sDate` is since `startTime` and `endTime` both contain dates which, in some worlds, could differ within a row. From whence comes the list of "everyone"? When Zelmo retires, but still has rows in the table, you'll never get any more "everyone all at once" results without separate knowledge of the New & Improved _everyone_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible option is something like the following. You can see it working in [this Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zCw93hkp).

```
WITH ranges AS
 (
 SELECT t startTime, LEAD(t) OVER(ORDER BY t) endTime, DATEDIFF(mi, t, LEAD(t) OVER(ORDER BY t)) duration
 FROM 
  (
   SELECT startTime t FROM @tmpSchedules
   UNION
   SELECT endTime FROM @tmpSchedules
  ) c
 )
SELECT t.sDate, r.startTime, r.endTime, r.duration
FROM ranges r INNER JOIN @tmpSchedules t
  on r.startTime >= t.startTime AND r.endTime <= t.endTime
GROUP BY t.sDate, r.startTime, r.endTime, r.duration
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) FROM @tmpSchedules)
ORDER BY r.startTime
```

The `ranges` CTE gets all of the possible blocks by `union`ing the `startTime`s/`endTime`s together. (i.e. If a person started work at 8:00 and no one else starts or ends until 8:30, then 8:00 to 8:30 is a block that has the same number of workers for the entire period). It's not necessary to use a CTE for this, but I thought it was easier to read.

The main query joins those potential ranges with the actual data and the `having` clause checks whether the number of workers working in that range is equal to the total number of workers.

This works with your test data, but possibly you'd need to tweak how it handles edge cases (e.g. if a worker stopped working and restarted at the same time, this would report that as two separate ranges) or if you need to handle shifts that extend into the next day (I simply did `GROUP BY sDate` since it wasn't clear how/whether that needed to be handled).

Comment: EdmCoff and Patrick both had great solutions however I have an older version of sql and don't have access to perform string aggregates so one worked better than the other. to answer the question of dtdate it was required because some schedules cross midnight, however the whole duration of a schedule belongs to the day the schedule began on so it allows for day filtering, as there could be 1-10 people scheduled at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I doubled up on your exampled data:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (sDate DATE, startTime DATETIME, endTime DATETIME, name NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @table (sDate, startTime, endTime, name) VALUES
('2023-02-23 00:00:00.000', '2023-02-23 08:00:00.000', '2023-02-23 10:00:00.000', 'John'),
('2023-02-23 00:00:00.000', '2023-02-23 10:30:00.000', '2023-02-23 12:00:00.000', 'John'),
('2023-02-23 00:00:00.000', '2023-02-23 13:00:00.000', '2023-02-23 17:00:00.000', 'John'),
('2023-02-23 00:00:00.000', '2023-02-23 08:30:00.000', '2023-02-23 09:00:00.000', 'Anita'),
('2023-02-23 00:00:00.000', '2023-02-23 09:30:00.000', '2023-02-23 20:00:00.000', 'Anita');

INSERT INTO @table (sDate, startTime, endTime, name) VALUES
('2023-02-24 00:00:00.000', '2023-02-24 09:00:00.000', '2023-02-24 11:00:00.000', 'John'),
('2023-02-24 00:00:00.000', '2023-02-24 11:30:00.000', '2023-02-24 12:00:00.000', 'John'),
('2023-02-24 00:00:00.000', '2023-02-24 14:00:00.000', '2023-02-24 18:00:00.000', 'John'),
('2023-02-24 00:00:00.000', '2023-02-24 09:30:00.000', '2023-02-24 10:00:00.000', 'Anita'),
('2023-02-24 00:00:00.000', '2023-02-24 10:30:00.000', '2023-02-24 21:00:00.000', 'Anita');
```

Then used this to get an answer:

```
DECLARE @SecondsRange INT = 599;

;WITH MinuteRanges AS (
SELECT CAST('00:00:00.0000000' AS TIME) AS RangeStart, DATEADD(MICROSECOND,-1,DATEADD(SECOND,@SecondsRange+1,CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME))) AS RangeEnd
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND,@SecondsRange+1,RangeStart), DATEADD(SECOND,@SecondsRange+1,RangeEnd)
  FROM MinuteRanges
 WHERE DATEADD(SECOND,@SecondsRange+1,RangeStart) > RangeStart
), AllInRanges AS (
SELECT t.sDate, mr.RangeStart, mr.RangeEnd, STRING_AGG(name,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) AS WhosIn, a.allNames, 
CASE WHEN LAG(mr.RangeEnd,1) OVER (PARTITION BY sDate ORDER BY mr.RangeStart) IS NULL THEN 1
     WHEN LAG(mr.RangeEnd,1) OVER (PARTITION BY sDate ORDER BY mr.RangeStart) <> DATEADD(MICROSECOND,-1,mr.RangeStart) THEN 1 
 END AS IsRangeStart
  FROM MinuteRanges mr
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @table t
      ON mr.RangeStart >= CAST(t.startTime AS TIME)
      AND mr.RangeEnd <= CAST(t.endTime AS TIME)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT STRING_AGG(name,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) AS allNames FROM (SELECT name FROM @table GROUP BY name) a) a
 GROUP BY t.sDate, mr.RangeStart, mr.RangeEnd, a.allNames
 HAVING STRING_AGG(name,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) = a.allNames
), Periods AS (
SELECT sDate, RangeStart, RangeEnd, WhosIn
  FROM AllInRanges
 WHERE IsRangeStart = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT a.sDate, a.RangeStart, r.RangeEnd, a.WhosIn
  FROM Periods a
    INNER JOIN AllInRanges r
      ON DATEADD(MICROSECOND,1,a.RangeEnd) = r.RangeStart
      AND a.sDate = r.sDate
)

SELECT sDate, RangeStart, MAX(RangeEnd) AS RangeEnd, 
RIGHT('0' + CAST(((DATEDIFF(SECOND,RangeStart, MAX(RangeEnd))+1)/3600)    AS VARCHAR(2)),2)+':'+
RIGHT('0' + CAST(((DATEDIFF(SECOND,RangeStart, MAX(RangeEnd))+1)%3600)/60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2)+':'+
RIGHT('0' + CAST(((DATEDIFF(SECOND,RangeStart, MAX(RangeEnd))+1)%60)      AS VARCHAR(2)),2) AS Duration, 
       WhosIn
  FROM Periods
 GROUP BY sDate, RangeStart, WhosIn
 ORDER BY SDate, RangeStart
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

There's a variable in there that let's us tweak the granularity. 599 is 10 minute windows. We're not going to bring back an overlaps smaller than that.

First we generate a complete set of ranges for 24 hours at the granularity we asked for `MinutesRanges`.
Then we use that to find all the ranges where all the employees were clocked in at the same time, using the HAVING clause and comparing it to the CROSS APPLY where we fetch who all the employees are. There's a sneaky LAG windowed function in there too, that flags the start of a range for us `AllInRanges`.
Once we know all the ranges we care about, we can use a `rCTE` to group chain them together, using the first ranges `RangeStart` `Periods`.

Finally, we can select from `Periods` and group by the sDate and RangeStart to give us the full ranges where all employees where in, and the duration of that.

| sDate | RangeStart | RangeEnd | Duration | WhosIn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-23 | 08:30:00.0000000 | 08:59:59.9999990 | 00:30:00 | Anita, John |
| 2023-02-23 | 09:30:00.0000000 | 09:59:59.9999990 | 00:30:00 | Anita, John |
| 2023-02-23 | 10:30:00.0000000 | 11:59:59.9999990 | 01:30:00 | Anita, John |
| 2023-02-23 | 13:00:00.0000000 | 16:59:59.9999990 | 04:00:00 | Anita, John |
| 2023-02-24 | 09:30:00.0000000 | 09:59:59.9999990 | 00:30:00 | Anita, John |
| 2023-02-24 | 10:30:00.0000000 | 10:59:59.9999990 | 00:30:00 | Anita, John |
| 2023-02-24 | 11:30:00.0000000 | 11:59:59.9999990 | 00:30:00 | Anita, John |
| 2023-02-24 | 14:00:00.0000000 | 17:59:59.9999990 | 04:00:00 | Anita, John |

This might not be the most performant method, so YMMV.